# Materialized View: What is the Update Trigger property?

Tags: oracle, trigger, materialized-view, oracle-18c

I've created a materialized view in an Oracle 18c database.

When I look at the *Info* tab of the materialized view in Toad, I see that there is a property called ***Update Trigger***.

[image]

What does the *Update Trigger* property represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the remains of an ancient feature called updatable snaphots that later became updatable materialized views.

Originally materialized views were called snapshots. The values for `Update Trigger` and `Update Log` come from the `UPDATE_TRIG` and `UPDATE_LOG` columns of `ALL|DBA|USER_SNAPSHOTS`, a view that was last documented properly in Oracle 8i: [ALL_SNAPSHOTS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/index.htm). The 9.0 documentation of that view is actually broken.

Oracle 7: [Snapshot Site Replication](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/SD273/ch5.htm)

> Updatable Snapshot Architecture
>
> In addition to the objects created for read-only snapshots that are
> described [*], when you create an updatable snapshot, two additional
> objects are created at the snapshot site:
>
> - Oracle creates a table, named USLOG$_snapshot_name, to store the    ROWID and timestamp of rows updated in the snapshot. The timestamp
>   column is not updated until the log is first used by a snapshot
>   refresh.
> - Oracle creates an AFTER ROW trigger on the snapshot base table to insert the ROWIDs and timestamps of updated and deleted rows into the
>   updatable snapshot log. The trigger is named USTRG$_snapshot_name.

In Oracle 8i, snapshots were renamed to materialized views, and updatable snapshots became updatable materialized views. The above allowed users to perform DML operations on snapshots/materialized views, and those changes could be replicated back to the master tables.

Updatable materialized views were part of a feature called Advanced Replication. That is a feature that I have yet to see in a real database. About 6 years ago I found a 10.2 customer database in which someone tried to set up this feature in 2008 but failed to do it. I have never ever seen this anywhere else.

Advanced Replication became deprecated in 12.1, and desupported in 12.2.

Answer (score 2):

That's the way materialized views work. They essentially create a copy of the results of the query in the view. The base table(s) used in that query  are automatically updated when the base table changes. That is implemented via a **trigger** on the base table that records all changes into a **materialized view log** associated to that base table.

A subsequent process then reads that log to apply the changes to the materialized view table. That application can be automatic or manual.

This: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/materialized-views has a nice illustration of how this works:

[image]

Comment: This could be the correct answer, just not for this question. The question is about another feature.

Comment: Hmmm. The question IS about materialized views, isn't it ?